# Ruby: Undefined method `length' for 1:Integer (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, methods

```
def print_array(arr)
  # YOUR WORK HERE
  i = 0
  if i > arr.length

  else
    p print_array(arr[i])
    i += 1
  end
end
```

I get this error: :4:in `print_array': undefined method` length' for 1:Integer (NoMethodError)
whenever I attempt to run the code. Not understanding what the problem is.

Comment: Try running your code with the following line of code inserted at the beginning: `puts "arr = #{arr}"`.

Comment: Another quick debug method: `p(arr: arr)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're effectively calling `print_array(1)`, which isn't a valid call.

What you need is either:

```rb
print_array([ arr[i] ])
```

Alternatively you can use an array slice:

```rb
print_array(arr[i,1])
```

Or to change the args so that it's an array by default:

```rb
def print_array(*arr)
   # ...
end
```

Where you then call it initially without the `[ ... ]`.

I'd suggest the fixed up version of the code looks like this:

```rb
def print_array(arr, index = 0)
  return if index > arr.length

  p arr[index]

  print_array(arr, index + 1)
end
```

Or possibly:

```
def print_array(arr)
  return unless arr.any?

  p arr[0]

  print_array(arr.drop(1))
end
```

Comment: I initially tried to test it by calling it as ``` print_array([1, 2, 3]) ``` but was getting that error before the code reached the call.  When I add the asterisk to the parameter it does seem to work, I'm just getting a system stack error, but that's an issue with the recursion that I'm trying to practice.  Still don't understand why I would get the initial error as #length is definitely an in-built method to Ruby.

Comment: It's a built-in method...for Array. You're calling it with an Integer. Note that you're making a call in your `else` block that's incorrect.